# Introducir palabras dentro de un array desde terminal utilizando C

Tags: array, c

Quisiera poder ingresar una o mas palabras desde la consola y que cada carácter lo guarde dentro de un array, es decir, si ingreso dentro de consola `hola stackoverflow` pueda almacenar una array con los caracteres que fueron ingresados:

`{'h','o','l','a',' ','s','t','a','c','k','o','v','e','r','f','l','o','w'}`

Cabe mencionar que el tamaño del array es de acorde al numero de caracteres ingresado, actualmente **únicamente** conozco `scanf()` y `getchar()` y he estado tratando un buen rato, sin embargo con getchar() obtengo el carácter adicional `\0` por lo que no puedo guardar únicamente el carácter que deseo y no conozco alguna otra herramienta para poder solventar el problema por el momento.

también he probado con este codigo

```
char strings[3][256]; //3 palabras cada una con espacio para 255 caracteres
scanf("%s %s %s", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);
printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);
```

pero no puedo ingresar mas de 3 palabras y como cada palabra tiene un espacio fijo de 255 caracteres queda bastante espacio basura dentro del array junto a la palabra ingresada.

Comment: No sera mejor leer la linea entera usando `fgets`?

Comment: @Pablochaches soy nuevo en C y desconocía esa función, la verdad ha funcionado pero si defino un array por ejemplo de 50 espacios y utilizo solo 4 de este quedan 46 espacios basura,  que puedo hacer para eliminar los datos basura del arreglo que queda? hay alguna función incorporada en C para eso?

Comment: Los string en C terminan en un `\0`, asi que para ver el final solo tienes que buscar por ese caracter.

Comment: @Cucho esa duda que tienes podría perfectamente estar en otra pregunta de stackoverflow, no crees?